# Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section 4.8

Tags: java, android, xml, google-developers-console

I published my first app on play store a few days ago (May 27th) and after 2 days I received an email from google with the following text:

[image]

I tried to release the update by adding a privacy URL in the console and within the application but it is still removed.

First I used firebase, then I removed it. I'm using only AdMob and Rewarded Video Ads

I generated my privacy link via: https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com. I have selected Google Play Services and AdMob

My button <kbd>See Privacy Policy</kbd>:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://candy-clicker.flycricket.io/privacy.html");
 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Manifest Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.dr0p3r.clickmoreforwin">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" /> <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <activity android:name=".ShopActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme">
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="MY ADS ID" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I didn't find anything about my problem at that link

Comment: That is because Stack Overflow is not a source of support for app distribution channels like the Play Store, which is the point being made at that Meta post.

Comment: I think it's a problem concerning the use of advertising id within the app (from what the email says)